# Web scraping into a single string with request?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, lxml

I am trying to scrape some pages from yelp. The way I did it, they turn out into a list. However I would like them to be in one single string. Any elegant solutions?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
baseurl = "url"
yelp1 = requests.get(baseurl).text
# turns into a list. this is why i did the following:
overviews= ""
for site in yelp1:
    overviews = overviews + site + " "
```

Any ideas how to do it directly without adding the second loop?

Comment: provided `yelp1` is your list, just use `.join()`. So, `overviews = ' '.join(yelp1)`

Comment: thanks! eventually any way how to do it in the request line immediately?

Comment: probably. I'd have to see the whole code with the url